# How to plot state space variables against time on unit step input?

Tags: control, matlab, step-response, plot

I have a system defined in state space model with the following matrices

A =

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
       -1280  & -254  &  -26 &  3400 \\
        -1    &  0    &  0   &   0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

B =

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

C = 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

D= 0

As you see I have 4 state variables , I want to plot them against time with step input in matlab.

Comment: The simplest way would be to run a simulation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry but can you elaborate more ?

Comment: You have the initial state. You have the state-space equation. These two are giving you the *momentary* change in the state (it's time derivative at time 0). You multiply it by time step and add to the current state to obtain the next one. The smaller time steps, the more accurate it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like matlab step function can already do that

I have solved it using the following equations:

```
[y,t,x] = step(ss_model,1) % X here will have trajectories for the 
x1 = [ 1 0 0 0]*x';
x2 = [ 0 1 0 0]*x';
x3 = [ 0 0 1 0]*x';
x4 = [ 0 0 0 1]*x';
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way:

```
close all; clear all; clc;

A = [0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0; -1280 -254 -26 3400; -1 0 0 0];
B = [0;0;1;0];
C = [1 0 0 0];
D = [0];

sys = ss(A,B,C,D);
[y,t,x] = step(sys);
plot(t,x);
legend('x1','x2','x3','x4');
```